# How to add real-time data in a dual-Y-axis ZedGraph graph using C#?

Tags: c#, real-time, zedgraph

For my project, I need to add and update real-time data to my dual y-axis graph. The Y and Y2 values share the same X value, and I created it already. Now I have a function that adds the new point pairs to the curve lists.

Here is my problem: My Y and Y2 values are always added to the curve list of the first curve. How can I get the Y2 value added to the second curve list in my graph?

Here is my function code:

```
    private void AddDataToGraph(ZedGraphControl zg1, XDate xValue, double yValue1, double yValue2)
    {
        // Make sure that the curvelist has at least one curve.
        if (zg1.GraphPane.CurveList.Count <= 0)
            return;

        // Get the first CurveItem in the graph.
        LineItem curve = zg1.GraphPane.CurveList[0] as LineItem;

        if (curve == null)
            return;

        // Get the PointPairList.
        IPointListEdit list = curve.Points as IPointListEdit;
        IPointListEdit list2 = curve.Points as IPointListEdit;

        // If this is null, it means the reference at curve.Points does not
        // support IPointListEdit, so we won't be able to modify it.
        if (list == null || list2 == null)
            return;

        // Add new data points to the graph.
        list.Add(xValue, yValue1);
        list2.Add(xValue, yValue2);

        // Force redraw.
        zg1.Invalidate();
    }
```

How can he Y2 values be added to the 2nd curve list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found a possible solution myself. Here are my code changes:

```
private void AddDataToGraph(ZedGraphControl zg1, XDate xValue, double yValue1, double yValue2)
    {
        // Make sure that the curvelist has at least one curve
        if (zg1.GraphPane.CurveList.Count <= 0)
            return;

        // Get the first CurveItem in the graph
        LineItem curve = zg1.GraphPane.CurveList[0] as LineItem;
        LineItem curve2 = zg1.GraphPane.CurveList[1] as LineItem;

        if (curve == null || curve2 == null)
            return;

        // Get the PointPairList
        IPointListEdit list = curve.Points as IPointListEdit;
        IPointListEdit list2 = curve2.Points as IPointListEdit;
        // If this is null, it means the reference at curve.Points does not
        // support IPointListEdit, so we won't be able to modify it
        if (list == null || list2 == null)
            return;

        // add new data points to the graph
        list.Add(xValue, yValue1);
        list2.Add(xValue, yValue2);

        // force redraw
        zg1.Invalidate();
    }
```

The important thing is to use the index in the "CurveList[i]". So [0] is my curve with the Y values and [1] is my curve with the Y2 values, and so on.

I hope this helps anybody who has the same or similar problem.

Comment: I've not seen the invalidate() syntax. I just use this.Refresh();

Answer (score 1):

Here's a "nicer" implementation of above:

```
    private void AddDataToGraph(ZedGraphControl zg1, XDate xValue, double[] yValues)
    {
        GraphPane myPane = zg1.GraphPane;
        // Make sure that the curvelist has at least one curve
        if (myPane.CurveList.Count <= 0)
            return;
        else if (myPane.CurveList.Count != yValues.Length)
            return;

        for (int i = 0; i < yValues.Length; i++ )
        {
            ((IPointListEdit)myPane.CurveList[i].Points).Add(xValue, yValues[i]);
        }
        // force redraw
        zg1.Invalidate();
    }
```